# Discrepancy in SE reputation graph

Tags: bug, deleted-answers, reputation-graph, deleted-accounts

Since June 3 my reputation for "IT Security" is showing different values in [SE reputation graph](https://stackexchange.com/users/246559/mgibsonbr?tab=reputation) and [everywhere else](https://stackexchange.com/users/246559/mgibsonbr?tab=accounts). This happened just after an user were removed, making me lose all reputation from his upvotes and my answer/edit to one of his questions (I'd link to it, but I don't have enough rep to even find it again). I waited a while to see if recalc would fix it, but so far nothing's changed (before asking this, I also [manually triggered recalc](https://security.stackexchange.com/reputation), but the values are still the same).

[image]
[image]

It seems when this user was deleted, all reputation changes coming from him were removed from the history, since there's no "drop" in the graph that day I lost 67 points. My first guess were that `-10 User was removed` was the culprit (since the discrepancy is also 10 points), however **the graph** is the lower one...

Another explanation would be: since that user [likely] upvoted my answer to his own question, when he was deleted the history removed his upvote twice: once because "he upvoted me", and another because "I had X upvotes in an answer that was deleted".

**Update:** I understand it might be a caching problem, that's why I waited almost 3 weeks to report. However, note that until June 3 both the graph and the site were in sync, and after that they still are in sync, but with a discrepancy of `10`:

```
Date              Graph                    Site
         before del | after del  before del | after del
-------------------------------------------------------
June 1         1038   971              1038   971
June 2         1043   976              1043   976
June 3                966                     976        (-77 | -67)?
June 4                986                     996
June 5                996                    1006
...
June 19              1056                    1066
June 20              1066                    1076
```

Comment: I don't think it's a caching problem - the discrepancy appeared at the same day an user was deleted, and has been pretty consistent for almost 3 weeks. Please check the update